# Push notification not being sent from loopback

Tags: android, node.js, push-notification, loopbackjs

I have used the loopback sample application "loopback-3.x" given on:https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-example-push. The correct server key was given in config, then created an application and registered a device with that application. Then I tried sending a push notification with "notifyById" method. The console shows a succes message like:

```
loopback:component:push:provider:gcm Sending message to ["devicetokengiven"]: {"params":{"timeToLive":3600,"data":{"message":"sfwsed","messageFrom":"sdefsdf","badge":2}}}
loopback:component:push:provider:gcm GCM result: {"multicast_id":multicast_id,"success":1,"failure":0,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"message_id":"0:23423555466%24324434354"}]}
```

It seems to be a success, but the device doesnt get any push notification. What could be the issue? Any help would be appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately their last release simply doesn't work with FCM. However, in their last commit they have a change which requires an object with the attributes (messageFrom and alert) and then they convert these att to body and title. Moreover, there is a PR where someone adds another notification's attributes, but I don't think it will be merged soon.

Solutions:

> Reference your module to their last commit: `"loopback-component-push": "git://github.com/strongloop/loopback-component-push.git#dce16d9be30d80e258c2ac5e3dc1f74276f2b0cd"`and send {messageFrom: "your title", alert: "your body"}

or

> Use a simple FCM node module or even a HTTP request. Will make your life much easier.